# Action Reducer function not being called

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch from django REST api but the dispatch action reducer won't work. I'm using Material UI, Hooks, Redux.

Action Reducer code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { GET_NOTE } from './types';

// GET NOTE
export const getNote = () => (dispatch) =>  {
    console.log('Contacting API');
    axios.get('/api/note/')
        .then(response => {
            console.log('api contact');
            dispatch({
                type: GET_NOTE,
                payload: response.data
            });
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

Functional component calling it:

```
import React from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getNote } from '../../redux/actions/note'

import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    container: {
        minHeight: '100vh',
        paddingTop: '25vh',
    },
}))


const Note = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    console.log(getNote());

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('componentDidMount is useEffect in React Hooks');
        getNote();
    }, [])

    Note.propTypes = {
        note: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }
    return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
        <Typography>
            This is note page.
        </Typography>
    </div>
);}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    note: state.note.note
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    { getNote }
)(Note);
```

I tracked where the code was not running and it was on getNote() function in 'Note' functional component. The console was something just like this:

```
note.jsx:21 dispatch => {
console.log('Contacting API');
  axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.get('/api/note/').then(response => {
    console.log('api contact');
    dispatch({
      type: _types__W…
note.jsx:24 componentDidMount is useEffect in React Hooks
```

Github link to code: https://github.com/PranishShresth/E-classmate

Comment: Just learned about connect( ) is not used in hooks, digging in the documentation, will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't call the injected `getNote` that `connect` is passed for you through `props`, you call the original function that you import.

You can use `connect` in function components but `react-redux` also gives you [`useSelector`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector) and [`useDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch) [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks) that can replace the `connect` HOC

Example using `connect`

```js
const Note = props => {
  useEffect(props.getNote, [])

  return ...
}

// don't define propTypes inside the component body
Note.propTypes = { 
  note: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  note: state.note.note
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, 
  { getNote }
)(Note)
```

Example using hooks

```js
const Note = () => {
  const note = useSelector(state => state.note.note)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getNote())
  }, [])

  return ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I messed up by trying to merge hooks unknowingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use props.getNote() and dispatch it and once you do it, you should be good.